# Function sizes including static data in other sections

Tags: c, linux, assembly, object-files, code-size

Is there a convenient way to find the full size cost of a compiled function?
Measuring function code sizes is simple (with `objdump` or `nm`), but what if a function generates in a non-text section static data such as jump tables from `switch`es.
How can I conveniently add the sizes of those (especially in situations where there's multiple functions per object file and several of them each reference a jumptable) to the text size of a function?

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do this.  The ELF object file format does not provide an association between the jump tables and the functions, so it doesn't even seem like the desired information is present without some guesswork.

Comment: What about static data (like a string literal) used by multiple functions?  Does it get attributed to all of them?  None of them?  Divided equally?

Comment: There are also initializers that might go to data/static data section

Comment: I'd say, compile with the function. Then compile with an empty stub and compare. Still won't give much though, because it might get inlined here and there.

Comment: For now, `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections` seems like a viable way to split it all up per function for information purposes, although it sometimes does affect codegen a bit like the gcc manual says.

Comment: Another sometimes-significant source of static size is SIMD vector constants when auto-vectorizing.  e.g. multiple 4-byte `float` constants replicated into 32-byte vectors (so they can be memory operands directly without AVX-512, without needing `vbroadcastss` loads).

Comment: Where are you starting from? Do you know about `size a.out` (if you are on Linux, are you on Linux?)

Comment: @ADBeveridge Yes. For now, `size -A file.o` after the file was compiled with `-ffunction-section -fdata-section` is the closest to an ideal solution, although something that works without requiring `-ffunction-section -fdata-section`  would be better.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ideally, I'd like to easily show both how much space a function requires and how much of it is shared with other functions.